# How can I write the following recursive python method correctly?

Tags: python, recursion, methods

I am a programming beginner, and want to improve my skills. So I decided to implement some algorithms; i.e. I implemented a class `BTree(object)` which represents a binary search tree . I  struggle with recursive methods. I tried to code a method `minEl(self)` which should return the min element of the tree, but each time I call the method, the following error occurs:

`minEl()` takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

I am gratefull for any help.

Well here is my code:

```
class BTree(object):
'Modelliert einen binären Suchbaum mit mehreren nützlichen Methoden'

  def __init__ (self, key, ltree = None, rtree = None, val = None, ):
    self.ltree = ltree
    self.rtree = rtree
    self.key   = key
    self.val   = val

  def minEl(self):
    if self.ltree == None:
      return self.key
    else:
      return self.minEl(self.ltree)
```

Answer (score 3):

self argument is the object on which you call a method (the object before dot).

I think:

```
self.ltree.minEl()
```

is what you want instead of self.minEl(self.ltree).

Comment: thanks alot! Are you sure it doesen't ? I just tried a very small tree :    b = BTree(15,BTree(8,BTree(5,BTree(2),BTree(7))))
and called : b.minEl() , in this case it worked fine

Comment: I am pretty sure. I think it computes the key of the leftmost leaf. Do you want more help in this matter?

Comment: If the search tree is properly initialized, the leftmost element is the smallest.

Comment: Huh, my fault. Of course. Because of the way it was used I overlooked "search" in "binary search tree". Of course it is the smallest in this case.